# How to parse signed zero?

Tags: c#, parsing, zero

Is it possible to parse signed zero?
I tried several approaches but no one gives the proper result:

```
float test1 = Convert.ToSingle("-0.0");
float test2 = float.Parse("-0.0");
float test3;
float.TryParse("-0.0", out test3);
```

If I use the value directly initialized it is just fine:

```
float test4 = -0.0f;
```

So the problem seems to be in the parsing procedures of c#. I hope somebody could tell if there is some option or workaround for that.

The difference could only be seen by converting to binary:

```
var bin= BitConverter.GetBytes(test4);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there is no way to force `float.Parse` (or `Convert.ToSingle`) to respect negative zero. It just works like this (ignores sign in this case). So you have to check that yourself, for example:

```
string target = "-0.0";            
float result = float.Parse(target, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (result == 0f && target.TrimStart().StartsWith("-"))
    result = -0f;
```

If we look at [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/57ee22e6086af5dfc06651dc002e24a71c3999ee/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Number.Parsing.cs) for coreclr, we'll see (skipping all irrelevant parts):

```
private static bool NumberBufferToDouble(ref NumberBuffer number, ref double value)
{
    double d = NumberToDouble(ref number);
    uint e = DoubleHelper.Exponent(d);
    ulong m = DoubleHelper.Mantissa(d);

    if (e == 0x7FF)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (e == 0 && m == 0)
    {
        d = 0; // < relevant part
    }

    value = d;
    return true;
}
```

As you see, if mantissa and exponent are both zero - value is explicitly assigned to `0`. So there is no way you can change that.

Full .NET implementation has `NumberBufferToDouble` as `InternalCall` (implemented in pure C\C++), but I assume it does something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that is the obvious solution. I need to parse millions of strings and that will slow down the process. I am still hoping that someone could suggest a faster option.

Comment: @mortal but how much of your millions of strings are zeros? Because if it's not zero - overhead is just one comparision with `0f`, which I think is completely negligible compared to time it takes parsing string to float.

Comment: I don't know how much they are, but the if statement will slow the parsing of all values. After each parse there will be a check if it is 0 or not.

Comment: @mortal yes but this check costs almost no time **compared** to the code which parses string to float. Anyway, I think there is no direct solution.

Comment: @mortal: The code for parsing floating-point is some of the slowest string conversion code in the framework, never mind one additional check for negative zero (it's *hard*). If speed really is a great concern, you should first and foremost look at whether you can reduce the values to restricted forms that allow faster parsing, and if you need your floating-point values to roundtrip exactly, to the point where you need to distinguish negative zero, you probably shouldn't be using a decimal representation to begin with.

Comment: I am not saying that the custom rules are something bad. I just found something I didn't now and I was hoping that someone could have better solution than me.

Comment: I would have thought this answer would be very fast. It's likely to take a small proportion of the overall parsing time.

Comment: @mortal I think you are fall into the mental trap which makes people think that fast code and short (concise) code are the same. They are not. In computer science, quite the opposite is true: often, short simple algorithms often are terribly inefficient, and efficient algorithms are much longer. Here, a single call to `Parse` is likely to take several orders of magnitude more time than a single comparison with `==`. I'd not be surprised if the ratio was 1000:1. Anyway, never apply micro-optimizations unless you profiled your code first.

Answer (score 9):

## Updated Results

**Summary**

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 100 times (averaged/scale)

Tests limited to 10 digits
Name            |      Time |    Range | StdDev |      Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine Unchecked  |  9.645 ms | 0.259 ms |   0.30 |  32,815,064 | Yes
Mine Unchecked2 | 10.863 ms | 1.337 ms |   0.35 |  36,959,457 | Yes
Mine Safe       | 11.908 ms | 0.993 ms |   0.53 |  40,541,885 | Yes
float.Parse     | 26.973 ms | 0.525 ms |   1.40 |  91,755,742 | Yes
Evk             | 31.513 ms | 1.515 ms |   7.96 | 103,288,681 | Base


Test Limited to 38 digits 
Name            |      Time |    Range | StdDev |      Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine Unchecked  | 17.694 ms | 0.276 ms |   0.50 |  60,178,511 | No
Mine Unchecked2 | 23.980 ms | 0.417 ms |   0.34 |  81,641,998 | Yes
Mine Safe       | 25.078 ms | 0.124 ms |   0.63 |  85,306,389 | Yes
float.Parse     | 36.985 ms | 0.052 ms |   1.60 | 125,929,286 | Yes
Evk             | 39.159 ms | 0.406 ms |   3.26 | 133,043,100 | Base


Test Limited to 98 digits (way over the range of a float)
Name            |      Time |    Range | StdDev |      Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine Unchecked2 | 46.780 ms | 0.580 ms |   0.57 | 159,272,055 | Yes
Mine Safe       | 48.048 ms | 0.566 ms |   0.63 | 163,601,133 | Yes
Mine Unchecked  | 48.528 ms | 1.056 ms |   0.58 | 165,238,857 | No
float.Parse     | 55.935 ms | 1.461 ms |   0.95 | 190,456,039 | Yes
Evk             | 56.636 ms | 0.429 ms |   1.75 | 192,531,045 | Base
```

Verifiably, `Mine Unchecked` is good for smaller numbers however when using powers at the end of the calculation to do fractional numbers it doesn't work for larger digit combinations, also because its just powers of 10 it plays with a i just a big switch statement which makes it marginally faster.

**Background**

Because of the various comments I got, and the work I put into this. I thought I’d rewrite this post with the most accurate benchmarks I could get. And all the logic behind them.

So when this first question come up, I had written my own benchmark framework and often just like writing a quick parser for these things and using unsafe code, 9 times out of 10 I can get this stuff faster than the framework equivalent.

At first this was easy, just write a simple logic to parse numbers with decimal point places, and I did pretty well, however the initial results weren’t as accurate as they could have been, because my test data was just using the ‘f’ format specifier, and would turn larger precision numbers in to short formats with only 0’s.

In the end I just couldn’t write a reliable parses to deal with exponent notation I.e `1.2324234233E+23`. The only way I could get the maths to work was using `BIGINTEGER` and lots of hacks to force the right precision into a floating point value. This turned to be super slow. I even went to the float IEEE specs and try to do the maths to construct it in bits, this wasn’t that hard, and however the formula has loops in it and was complicated to get right. In the end I had to give up on exponent notation.

So this is what I ended up with.

My testing framework runs on input data a list of 10000 floats as strings, which is shared across the tests and generated for each test run, A test run is just going through the each test (remembering it’s the same data for each test) and adds up the results then averages them. This is about as good as it can get. I can increase the runs to 1000 or factors more however they don’t really change. In this case because we are testing a method that takes basically one variable (a string representation of a float) there is no point scaling this as its not set based, however I can tweak the input to cater for different lengths of floats, i.e., strings that are 10, 20 right up to 98 digits. Remembering a float only goes up to 38 anyway.

To check the results I used the following, I have previously written a test unit that covers every float conceivable, and they work, except for a variation where I use Powers to calculate the decimal part of the number.

Note, my framework only tests 1 result set, and it's not part of the framework

```
private bool Action(List<float> floats, List<float> list)
{
   if (floats.Count != list.Count)
      return false; // sanity check

   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
   {
      // nan is a special case as there is more than one possible bit value
      // for it
      if (  floats[i] != list[i] && !float.IsNaN(floats[i]) && !float.IsNaN(list[i]))
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

In this case I'm testing again 3 types of input as shown below

**Setup**

```
// numberDecimalDigits specifies how long the output will be
private static NumberFormatInfo GetNumberFormatInfo(int numberDecimalDigits)
{
   return new NumberFormatInfo
               {
                  NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
                  NumberDecimalDigits = numberDecimalDigits
               };
}

// generate a random float by create an int, and converting it to float in pointers

private static unsafe string GetRadomFloatString(IFormatProvider formatInfo)
{
   var val = Rand.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
   if (Rand.Next(0, 2) == 1)
      val *= -1;
   var f = *(float*)&val;
   return f.ToString("f", formatInfo);
}
```

**Test Data 1**

```
// limits the out put to 10 characters
// also because of that it has to check for trunced vales and
// regenerates them
public static List<string> GenerateInput10(int scale)
{
   var result = new List<string>(scale);
   while (result.Count < scale)
   {
      var val = GetRadomFloatString(GetNumberFormatInfo(10));
      if (val != "0.0000000000")
         result.Add(val);
   }

   result.Insert(0, (-0f).ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, "-0");
      result.Insert(0, "0.00");
      result.Insert(0, float.NegativeInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, float.PositiveInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   return result;
}
```

**Test Data 2**

```
// basically that max value for a float
public static List<string> GenerateInput38(int scale)
{

   var result = Enumerable.Range(1, scale)
                           .Select(x => GetRadomFloatString(GetNumberFormatInfo(38)))
                           .ToList();

   result.Insert(0, (-0f).ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, "-0");
   result.Insert(0, float.NegativeInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, float.PositiveInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   return result;
}
```

**Test Data 3**

```
// Lets take this to the limit
public static List<string> GenerateInput98(int scale)
{

   var result = Enumerable.Range(1, scale)
                           .Select(x => GetRadomFloatString(GetNumberFormatInfo(98)))
                           .ToList();

   result.Insert(0, (-0f).ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, "-0");
   result.Insert(0, float.NegativeInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   result.Insert(0, float.PositiveInfinity.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
   return result;
}
```

These are the tests I used

**Evk**

```
private float ParseMyFloat(string value)
{
   var result = float.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   if (result == 0f && value.TrimStart()
                              .StartsWith("-"))
   {
      result = -0f;
   }
   return result;
}
```

**Mine safe**

I call it safe as it tries to check for invalid strings

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private unsafe float ParseMyFloat(string value)
{
   double result = 0, dec = 0;

   if (value[0] == 'N' && value == "NaN") return float.NaN;
   if (value[0] == 'I' && value == "Infinity")return float.PositiveInfinity;
   if (value[0] == '-' && value[1] == 'I' && value == "-Infinity")return float.NegativeInfinity;


   fixed (char* ptr = value)
   {
      char* l, e;
      char* start = ptr, length = ptr + value.Length;

      if (*ptr == '-') start++;
      

      for (l = start; *l >= '0' && *l <= '9' && l < length; l++)
         result = result * 10 + *l - 48;
      

      if (*l == '.')
      {
         char* r;
         for (r = length - 1; r > l && *r >= '0' && *r <= '9'; r--)
            dec = (dec + (*r - 48)) / 10;

         if (l != r)
            throw new FormatException($"Invalid float : {value}");
      }
      else if (l != length)
         throw new FormatException($"Invalid float : {value}");

      result += dec;

      return *ptr == '-' ? (float)result * -1 : (float)result;
   }
}
```

**Unchecked**

This fails for larger strings, but is ok for smaller ones

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private unsafe float ParseMyFloat(string value)
{
   if (value[0] == 'N' && value == "NaN") return float.NaN;
   if (value[0] == 'I' && value == "Infinity") return float.PositiveInfinity;
   if (value[0] == '-' && value[1] == 'I' && value == "-Infinity") return float.NegativeInfinity;

   fixed (char* ptr = value)
   {
      var point = 0;
      double result = 0, dec = 0;

      char* c, start = ptr, length = ptr + value.Length;

      if (*ptr == '-') start++;   

      for (c = start; c < length && *c != '.'; c++)
         result = result * 10 + *c - 48;

      if (*c == '.')
      {
         point = (int)(length - 1 - c);
         for (c++; c < length; c++)
            dec = dec * 10 + *c - 48;
      }

      // MyPow is just a massive switch statement
      if (dec > 0)
         result += dec / MyPow(point);

      return *ptr == '-' ? (float)result * -1 : (float)result;
   }
}
```

**Unchecked 2**

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private unsafe float ParseMyFloat(string value)
{

   if (value[0] == 'N' && value == "NaN") return float.NaN;
   if (value[0] == 'I' && value == "Infinity") return float.PositiveInfinity;
   if (value[0] == '-' && value[1] == 'I' && value == "-Infinity") return float.NegativeInfinity;


   fixed (char* ptr = value)
   {
      double result = 0, dec = 0;

      char* c, start = ptr, length = ptr + value.Length;

      if (*ptr == '-') start++;

      for (c = start; c < length && *c != '.'; c++)
         result = result * 10 + *c - 48;     

      // this division seems unsafe for a double, 
      // however i have tested it with every float and it works
      if (*c == '.')
         for (var d = length - 1; d > c; d--)
            dec = (dec + (*d - 48)) / 10;

      result += dec;

      return *ptr == '-' ? (float)result * -1 : (float)result;
   }
}
```

**Float.parse**

```
float.Parse(t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

#Original Answer

Assuming you don't need a `TryParse` method, I managed to use pointers and custom parsing to achieve what I think you want.

The benchmark uses a list of 1,000,000 random floats and runs each version 100 times, all versions use the same data

```
Test Framework : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Scale : 1000000
Name             |        Time |     Delta |  Deviation |       Cycles
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine Unchecked2  |   45.585 ms |  1.283 ms |       1.70 |  155,051,452
Mine Unchecked   |   46.388 ms |  1.812 ms |       1.17 |  157,751,710
Mine Safe        |   46.694 ms |  2.651 ms |       1.07 |  158,697,413
float.Parse      |  173.229 ms |  4.795 ms |       5.41 |  589,297,449
Evk              |  287.931 ms |  7.447 ms |      11.96 |  979,598,364
```

*Chopped for brevity*

**Note**, Both these version cant deal with extended format, `NaN`, `+Infinity`, or `-Infinity`. However, it wouldn't be hard to implement at little overhead.

I have checked this pretty well, though I must admit I haven't written any unit tests, so use at your own risk.

**Disclaimer**, I think Evk's `StartsWith` version could probably be more optimized, however it will still be (at best) slightly slower than `float.Parse`.

Comment: Does this parse scientific notation (1e2, 1.0E6), `NaN`, `+Infinity`, `-Infinity`?

Comment: @BurnsBA definitely not, ill add that to the notes

Comment: Also, I might suggest taking a look at the C# language spec. There's at least a version included with Visual Studio (`Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033`), but perhaps there's a more recent version online. Anyways, section 4.1.6 defines expected behavior when parsing floats. For instance, there's no need to throw an exception on an invalid float because returning `NaN` is expected.

Comment: Sorry, the spec mentions operations, not parsing, but I will keep the comment for reference.

Comment: @BurnsBA yeah just looking, thank for the link, i might upgrade it tomorrow, for future readers and re benchmark against what i already have, also write some tests!

Comment: One thing I've noticed (validated somewhat by your benchmark) is that specialized operations are often faster than BCL methods which must account for a wide variety of scenarios. Regardless of the "signed zero" problem, the OP may be better off with a custom (faster) parse against a predictable set of data. Of course, if the data isn't predictable, that's a different story.

Comment: @TimMedora exactly, there is a lot those `parse` methods do, so that was the idea behind the attempts, to reduce the degrees of freedom

Comment: One of the readons your solution is faster than the library is that it doesn't worry about the accuracy of the result. That might not matter in particular cases (perhaps including this case) but in the general case, there are strong expectations about accuracy. Repeatedly dividing a floating point number by 10 loses precision at every step.

Comment: @rici it's a very good point, It didbt seems to affect the accuracy of thr tests, however I guess I could just times it in and set the point with a pointer and a bitwise operation

Comment: @rici just fyi, i have confirmed that the division has no difference and tests perfectly again what int.parse does in the worst case scenarios.

Comment: What's a worst-case scenario? Just having more divisions isn't necessarily worse; it depends on the magnitude and direction of  the various  rounding errors. It's not at all easy to come up with an adequate test set.

Comment: @rici yeah i thought it was just longer divisions, however ill brute force and check every single bit combination, for float

Comment: You might want to take a look at David Gay's paper: https://www.ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf It's also easy to find non-paywalled copies of the paper by William Clinger. Certainly if you use double precision to produce a float result, errors are very uncommon. IIRC, Clinger claims that using long double to produce a double result fails less than 1% of the time, and double/float errors should be even rarer.

Comment: @rici so it turns out thr division adding to and the dividing on an initial zero (in double) is fine, and worked for every conceivable bit ergo and these parsing examples, however when I started adding E notation to it, and trying add positive negative powers the rounding and accuracy issue crept in, also the fact that it passed every float combination in this situation maybe platform specific. So I'm guessing if I can convert the sign exponent and mantissa into bits it would save heaps of cycles for the extended notation and also solve the parsing of it

Comment: After reading the link and further reading it kind of made sense why thre Division worked the way it did well at least on this platform. And also why increasing powers didn't in further versions did not

Comment: Can you post full code of your benchmark if you still have it? I just wonder how my (well, obvious) version might be twice as slow as float.Parse. Chance that random float is exactly zero is basically non existing, and if it's non-zero - my version only does one additional comparision ( `== 0f`).

Comment: Thanks, updated results are somewhat closer to what I would expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
string target = "-0.0";  
decimal result= (decimal.Parse(target,
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to parse it as float (I tried your suggestion and it does not work for float).

Comment: This does parse a negative zero (as in, a `decimal` distinct from `0.0m`), as can be verified with `Decimal.GetBits`. Of course, `float` and `decimal` have different ranges and representations, so whether that's a solution depends.

Comment: I am not playing with words but based on your subject, i assumed you ultimate goal is to parse signed 0 only. and I think it will parse it.